# How to convert an event listener to a promise using Q

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Good day everyone, I'm new to nodejs and I'm trying to learn promises. I'm trying to implement a sort of menu that will execute certain functions based on user input. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
var q = require('q');
var readline = require('readline-sync');

function createNewPreset(){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var preset = {
        "name" : undefined,
        "unit" : undefined,
        "interval" : undefined,
        "files" : [],
    }
    deferred.resolve(preset);
    return deferred.promise;
}
function addPreset(){
    console.log("adding");
    var deferred = q.defer();
    createNewPreset()
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Gettind input in addPreset");
    })
    .then(getUserInput)
    .then(function(data){
        console.log("Adding data" + data);
    });
}
function getUserInput(){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var stdin = process.stdin;
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.once('data', function(data){
        data = data.toString().trim()
        if(data.length > 20){
                var err = new Error("The entered preset name is too long");
                deferred.reject(err);
        }
        else{
                deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function processChoice(input){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var error = undefined;
    var func;
    switch(input){
        case "a":
                func = addPreset;               
        break;
        case "q":
                func = function(){
                        process.exit();
                }
        break;
        default:
                error = new Error("Invalid menu option entered.");
            deferred.reject(error);
        break;
    }
    deferred.resolve(func);
    return deferred.promise;
}
function prompt(){
    var stdout = process.stdout;
       //indicates that prompt is being executed
    stdout.write("(tic): ");
    console.log("Waiting for input");
    getUserInput()
    .then(processChoice)
    .then(function(func){ func(); })
    .catch(function(err) {console.log(err)})
    .then(prompt);
}
prompt();
```

I believe the problem lies in `getUserInput()` and `addPreset()`, with the event listener. I'd like the promise chain to continue only after the event listener is activated, but I'm not sure how to do that to be honest.

Here are my results:

```
(tic): Waiting for input
a
adding
Gettind input in addPreset
(tic): Waiting for input
A
Adding dataA
[Error: Invalid menu option entered.]
(tic): Waiting for input
```

I'd like to make the chain wait on the event listener to execute before it continues. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: should `var stdout = process.stdin;` be `var stdout = process.stdout;` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few errors in your code

in no particular order

- `.then(function(func){ func(); })` should be `.then(function(func){ return func(); })` - because func returns a promise which you want to wait for, without the `return` there the process was continuing on before  `addPreset` resolved
- in several functions you created a deferred without using it - removed those
- other places you create a deferred which you resolve and return, just return a `q.resolve()`

The code below doesn't use `q` promises at all, I've changed to native `Promise` to test my answer - but it should be trivial to convert back to `q`

```
function createNewPreset(){
    return Promise.resolve({
        "name" : undefined,
        "unit" : undefined,
        "interval" : undefined,
        "files" : [],
    });
}
function addPreset(){
    console.log("adding");
    return createNewPreset()
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Gettind input in addPreset");
    })
    .then(getUserInput)
    .then(function(data){
        console.log("Adding data " + data);
    });
}
function getUserInput(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var stdin = process.stdin;
        stdin.resume();
        stdin.once('data', function(data){
            data = data.toString().trim()
            if(data.length > 20){
                var err = new Error("The entered preset name is too long");
                reject(err);
            }
            else{
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

function processChoice(input){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var error = undefined;
        var func;
        switch(input){
            case "a":
                func = addPreset;               
            break;
            case "q":
                func = function(){
                    process.exit();
                }
            break;
            default:
                error = new Error("Invalid menu option entered.");
                reject(error);
            break;
        }
        resolve(func);
    });
}
function prompt(){
    var stdout = process.stdout;
       //indicates that prompt is being executed
    stdout.write("(tic): ");
    console.log("PROMPT waiting for input");
    getUserInput()
    .then(processChoice)
    .then(function(func){ return func(); })
    .catch(function(err) {console.log(err)})
    .then(prompt);
}
prompt();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really need to work on being more attentive to details :)

Comment: Btw, is there any advantage to using Q as opposed to the native Promise?